# Adobe air on iOS - FileReference Download Error

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air

When I use the Download method of the FileReference class, everything works fine on Desktop and Android, but I get an error on iOS.

This is the code:

```
var req = new URLRequest(url);
var localRef:FileReference = new FileReference();
localRef.download(req);
```

On iOS I'm getting an Alert:

Download Error
File downloads not supported.

I already tried to NavigateToUrl() and it asks save the file in Dropbox or another App.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't use `FileReference` on mobile (or AIR, in general, though it does open the Load/Save dialog on desktop so there can be some use there). You should instead use `File` and `FileStream`, which give you far more control over the file system.

In this case, you could try to use `File.download()` and save it to `File.applicationStorageDirectory`, but I don't know if it will have any difference since it extends `FileReference`.

What I generally do is use `URLStream` instead of `URLLoader`. It gives you access to the raw bytes of the file you are downloading and then use `File` and `FileStream`

So something like (and this is untested off the top of my head, though I have used similar in the past):

```
var urlStream:URLStream = new URLStream();
urlStream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
urlStream.load(new URLLoader('url');

function completeHandler(e:Event):void {
    var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    urlStream.readBytes(bytes);

    var f:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath('filename');
    var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
    fs.open(f, FileMode.WRITE);
    fs.writeBytes(bytes);
    fs.close();
}
```

Now, obviously, there is a lot more you want to account for (errors, progress, etc). That should be enough to point you in the right direction, however.

It's possible to create a full download manager using this method (something I did for an iOS project two years ago), since you can save as-you-go to the file system rather than waiting until `Event.COMPLETE` fires (using the `ProgressEvent.PROGRESS` event). That allows you to avoid having a 500MB file in memory, something most devices can't handle.